# Showing changing data onto a Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I created a very simple map with a marker linked to changing coordinates. Every second the marker moves on the map depending on the new coordinates extracted from a json file.
Is it possible to show the changing coordinates in a fixed location of the map window?
Something similar to a legend but with changing text.
Something like that, but automated and without mouse click: https://tomik23.github.io/leaflet-examples/#05.coordinates-after-clicking-on-the-map

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer, useMap, useMapEvents} from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import './MapScreen.css';

const MapScreen = () => {
 function Location(){
    const [position, setPosition] = React.useState({});
    const map = useMapEvents({
        click(e) {
            map.locate()
            setPosition({lat: e.latlng.lat, lng: e.latlng.lng})

        },
        locationfound(e) {
            setPosition(e.latlng)
            map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
        },
    })
    return (
        <div className='overlay'>
            <h1>{position.lat}</h1>
            <h1>{position.lng}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

return (
    <div className='container'>
        <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />

            <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
                <Popup>
                    A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                </Popup>
            </Marker>

            {/*    Overlay map text*/}
            <Location/>

        </MapContainer>
    </div>
 );
}
export default MapScreen
```

Style.css ->

```
.leaflet-container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```